# How to format or convert numbers in DataGridView and Report so that the output results are the same in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, formatting, type-conversion, format

Dear All Master,

How to format or convert numbers in DataGridView and Report so that the output results are the same in vb.net.
if I set the Alignment loop to MiddleCenter then the output report format number does not change then I change it to alignment to middleright so that it changes the output format in the report. There may be other solutions so that I can format or convert datagridview perfectly.

Thanks

```
Desired Result in datagridview and report
Prop1        Prop2
1         120,000.00
2         130,000.00
3              22.50
```

before click button preview in form

[image: before button preview datagridview]

after click button preview in form

[image: after button preview datagridview]

result preview report

[image: preview report]

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub fillDataGridView1()
        Dim list As New List(Of Data)()
        list.Add(New Data With {
          .Prop1 = 1,
          .Prop2 = 120000
      })
        list.Add(New Data With {
          .Prop1 = 2,
          .Prop2 = 130000
      })
        list.Add(New Data With {
          .Prop1 = 3,
          .Prop2 = 22.5
      })

        DataGridView1.Columns.Add("Prop1", "Prop1")
        DataGridView1.Columns("Prop1").DataPropertyName = "Prop1"
        DataGridView1.Columns.Add("Prop2", "Prop2")
        DataGridView1.Columns("Prop2").DataPropertyName = "Prop2"
        DataGridView1.Columns("Prop2").HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
        DataGridView1.Columns("Prop2").DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
        DataGridView1.Columns("Prop2").DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2"
        DataGridView1.DataSource = list
    End Sub

    Private Class Data
        Public Property Prop1() As Integer
        Public Property Prop2() As Double
    End Class

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        KtReport1.Clear()
        For Each c As DataGridViewColumn In DataGridView1.Columns
            If c.ValueType Is GetType(Double) Then
                c.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2"
                c.DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight
            End If
        Next c
        KtReport1.AddDatagridView(DataGridView1)
        KtReport1.ShowPrintPreviewDialog()
    End Sub
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        fillDataGridView1()
    End Sub

End Class
```

REPORT AFTER CHANGE TO N2
[image: REPORT AFTER CHANGE TO N2]

Comment: What is KtReport1 and how is it defined?

Comment: @JonRoberts , "ktreport1" is kimtoo.reports i.e. Winforms Library

Comment: OK, not familiar with that. Just checked the NuGet package info for it and no documentation available, so can't help further.

Comment: Why do you have `.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "0.00##"` in one place and `.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N"` in another, when actually want `N2`?

Comment: @Jimi , I've changed the code to "N2" but the report results for the value `120000 and 130000` unchanged

Comment: @Jimi , I tried to make the uniform format to be "N2" but `23 should be 22.50

Comment: I gave it a look. This Component seems to factually ignore the Cells' Format specifier, it instead determines the format to apply based on the Cell's Alignment. So, if it's right-aligned, it formats the content as a generic number, if it's something else, it takes the value as string. It does the same thing also if you set the Type of the data to string, instead of, say, `double` or `decimal`. Or if you change the Format to, e.g., `C2`, to have currency representation -- This looks like a serious bug (and violates the *principle of least astonishment* :) -- No docs are provided

Comment: @KimTooFlex ,maybe all that can help me is the developer of kimtoo.reports. You can solve this problem because you are the developer of the library.