# How to change the format "N2" from DataTable and Show in DataGridView in vb.net

Tags: datatable, datagridview, frameworks, asenumerable

How to change the DataTable format to "N2" and Show in DataGridView in vb.net?. I want to change the format of the DataTable without going through the DataGridView format and displaying in the DataGridView. Please recommend the best solution. I tried but the result is still in the datagridview has not changed.

Thanks

```vb
Private Sub ImprovedCode()
    Dim dt As New DataTable("tbl")
    Dim dtColumn As New DataColumn With {.DataType = GetType(DateOnly), .ColumnName = "CreatedDate"}
    dt.Columns.Add(dtColumn)
    Dim dtColumn2 As New DataColumn With {.DataType = GetType(Double), .ColumnName = "Price"}
    dt.Columns.Add(dtColumn2)
    Dim dr As DataRow = dt.NewRow()
    dr(dtColumn) = DateOnly.FromDateTime(Date.Now)
    dr(dtColumn2) = 120000
    Dim dr1 As DataRow = dt.NewRow()
    dr1(dtColumn) = DateOnly.FromDateTime(Date.Now)
    dr1(dtColumn2) = 130000
    dt.Rows.Add(dr)
    dt.Rows.Add(dr1)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
End Sub
```

RESULT DATAGRIDVIEW

[image: RESULT DATAGRIDVIEW]

DESIRED RESULT DATAGRIDVIEW

[image: DESIRED RESULT DATAGRIDVIEW]

Comment: Something like that `130000.ToString("N2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` ?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv , Thanks for the reply from you but the output in DataGridView has not changed